# How to stop printing using if statement with openpyxl

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, openpyxl

I'm reading values from an excel workbook and I'm trying to stop printing when the value of a specific cell equals a string. Here is my code

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')

for sheet in wb.worksheets:
    nrows = sheet.max_row
    ncolumns = sheet.max_column
    for rowNum in range(20,sheet.max_row):
        Sub = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=3).value
        Unit = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=6).value
        Concentration = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=9).value
        com = rowNum[3]
        if Sub == "User:":
            pass
        else:
            print(Sub, Concentration, Unit)
```

The problem is that the if statement doesn't work. When I use type(Sub), python return `<type 'unicode'>`

Do you have any idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're test is failing. All strings in Excel files are returned as unicode objects but `"User:" == u"User:"`. Maybe the cells you are looking at have some whitespace that isn't visible in your debug statement. In this case it's useful to embed the string in a list when printing it `print([Sub])`

Alternatively, and this looks to be the case, you are getting confused between Excel's 1-based indexing and Python's zero based indexing. In you code the first cell to be looked at will be `C20` (`ws.cell(20, 3)`) but `rowNum[3]` is actually `D20`.

I also recommend you try and avoid using Python's `range` and the `max_column` and `max_row` properties unless you really need them. In your case, `ws.get_squared_range()` make more sense. Or, in openpyxl 2.4, which allows specify the known edges of a range of cells.

```
for row in get_squared_range(ws.min_colum, 20, ws.max_column, ws.max_row):
    Sub = row[2].value # 3rd item
    Unit = row[5].value
    Concentration = row[8].value
```

In openpyxl 2.4 `get_squared_range` can be replaced:

`for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=20):`

Comment: Thanks a lot. it was indeed a whitespace